# how to define a pytest plugin in a setuptools pyproject.toml?

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-fixtures

According to pytest documentation, plugins must be registered as entry points so I want ot find the pyproject.toml equivalent to:

```
entry_points={
    "pytest11": [
        "copie = pytest_copi.plugin",
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Setuptools documentation](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html#entry-points-for-plugins), the correct syntax for this entry point should be:

```ini
[project.entry-points.pytest11]
copie = "pytest_copie.plugin"
```

Comment: You don't need to quote the pytest11

Comment: then why is it quoted in the pyproject.toml example of the documentation ?

Comment: Because the example they used has a period (.) character in the group name.